# How to upload certain committed files in PhpStorm

Tags: upload, phpstorm

I am a php developer and already use phpstorm automatic uploading feature after committing a function, but sometimes it failed to upload to the ftp server due to some reasons.

In that situation(finished committing but not uploading), how can I re-upload those modified files (may 20~30 files, maybe more), really takes time to upload one by one. Besides, I just can't use "Sync with Deployed" function, because the project contains above ten thousand files and scattered in different folders. maybe someone can help me save time ....thanks in advance ^^

BTW, can I upload certain commitment file list committed before.

sorry, I am poor at typing git command @@

[image]

Comment: follow this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html

Answer (score 3):

You can open "Changed Files" scope in a Project view for example:

[image: scopes]

Then right click root folder > **Upload to ...** or **Synchronize with ...**

Comment: Wow!!  really thank you to save a engineer's time, this is magic~  

may I ask you how to  upload a certain history commitment file list in phpstorm  which is  committed sometime before,  because sometime I finish a feature via several commitment(phases), after finishing at final, I will upload all these modified files at once, is that possible to achieve? 

Thanks ^^

Comment: Not working..! with scope active sync/upload features behave just like the normal scope.

Answer (score 1):

**To upload all/partial file(s) from a commit, follow these steps:**

- **First**, increase your editor tab limit. (by default, you can open maximum 10 tabs only)

*File > Settings... > Editor > General > Editor Tabs > Closing Policy : Tab limit*

[image]

- **Second**, open all files from commit(s).

1. Open "Version Control" window from "Tool Window Bar"
2. Select "Log" tab
3. Select single/multiple commit(s) from the list
4. Select root directory(s) and press right click
5. Click on "Edit Source" (this will open all those committed files)

[image]

- **Third**, change "Project" to "Open Files", from Project window.

[image]

- **Finally**, deploy to FTP server.

1. Select all/partial individual file(s) from project window (**important note:** don't select directories)
2. Right click, go to "Deployment"
3. Click on, "Upload to..." and choose ftp server from the list

[image]

That's it, happy coding!